# When constraintMatchEnabled (false) is disabled, this method should not be called

Tags: optaplanner

I am trying to use score director in optaplnner like :

```
 Solver solver = solverFactory.buildSolver();
 ScoreDirectorFactory scoreDirectorFactory = solver.getScoreDirectorFactory();
 ScoreDirector guiScoreDirector = scoreDirectorFactory.buildScoreDirector();

 for (ConstraintMatchTotal constraintMatchTotal :guiScoreDirector.getConstraintMatchTotals()) {

 }
```

but i am getting following exception when i call getConstraintMatchTotals method:

```
 When constraintMatchEnabled (false) is disabled, this method should not be called.. Stacktrace follows:
    Message: When constraintMatchEnabled (false) is disabled, this method should not be called.
        Line | Method
    ->>  140 | getConstraintMatchTotals in org.optaplanner.core.impl.score.director.AbstractScoreDirector
    - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
    |     57 | solve                    in com.volcare.optaplanner.TaskPlanningController
    |     97 | index . . . . . . . . .  in     ''
    |    200 | doFilter                 in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
    |     63 | doFilter . . . . . . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
    |   1145 | runWorker                in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
    |    615 | run . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
    ^    744 | run                      in java.lang.Thread
```

solverconfig.xml

```
  <!-- Score configuration -->
  <scoreDirectorFactory>
    <scoreDefinitionType>HARD_SOFT_BIG_DECIMAL</scoreDefinitionType>
    <simpleScoreCalculatorClass>com.volcare.optaplanner.TaskPlanScoreCalculator</simpleScoreCalculatorClass>
    <!-- <scoreDrl>/taskPlanningScoreRules.drl</scoreDrl> -->
  </scoreDirectorFactory>
```

Comment: I am wondering what score director you use (only drools supports it out of the box, but the message seems off). Can you copy the <scoreDirectorFactory> element from your solver config here?

Comment: i am using simple java score calculator,i have added configuration in question.

Answer (score 1):

`SimpleScoreCalculator` (now called `EasyScoreCalculator`) does not support constraint matches. Solutions:

1. Use the Drools score calc (by using `<scoreDrl>` instead of
   `<simpleScoreCalculatorClass>` in your config. The Drools rule
   engine is smart enough to not just calculate the score, but also
   explain it by telling you about the constraint matches.
2. For `IncrementalScoreCalculator` we recently added the interface
   `ConstraintMatchAwareIncrementalScoreCalculator`, so the user can expose them (but unlike in Drools it doesn't just work magically - there's work to do). I think we should also support a similar interfacef or easy score calculation (`ConstraintMatchAwareEasyScoreCalculator`).

Note: The error message you got is not clear, but I 've improved that error message in 6.2.0.Beta2. Check if the error message is clearer once that's released.